# jQuery - Why hasData Does Not Work?

Tags: jquery

I assigned data into $clicked_row:

```
$clicked_row.data("row", data);
```

The following code does not work:

```
alert($clicked_row.hasData("row")); // want to have Boolean output
```

However, this works:

```
alert($clicked_row.data("row")); // output the data
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$.hasData($clicked_row);
```

Source for this solution: [the documentation on hasData](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.hasData/)

For a short discussion on why hasData isn't a property of data objects, [I refer you to this thread](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-hasdata-function-doesnt-exists). In summary, you should stick to using `.attr` to determining if the element has a given attribute set, rather than just wanting to know if it has *any* attribute set. It will return `undefined` if the attribute isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `"`

> alert($clicked_row.hasData("row **here**));

---

Or you just wrong assign data. From jQuery docs:

```
jQuery.data(document.body, 'foo', 52);
jQuery.data(document.body, 'bar', 'test');
```

**jQuery.data( element, key, value )**

**element**

- List item
- Type: Element
- The DOM element to associate with the data.

**key**

- Type: String
- A string naming the piece of data to set.

**value**

- Type: Object
- The new data value.

In your case you have `element`, `key` but you missed **`value`**